# How does Pyrokinesis work?

Tags: spells, wfrp-3e

How do the mechanics for the pyrokinesis (bright wizard spell) card work?

If I pass all initial checks for casting the spell, do I get to control the fire every turn until my recharge tokens run out, *without rerolling?*  What if the fire grows in size from consuming fuel? Do I have to reroll to see if I can continue to control it on subsequent turns?  Do I have to use up my action or maneuver to continue controlling it on subsequent turns?

Comment: asked a WFRP 3e GM... he's on his way. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you roll a chaos star, you are able to control and move the fire every turn until your recharge tokens run out *without rolling*.  If you roll a chaos star the card then becomes somewhat ambiguous IMO. The card states "The fire doubles in size! You must make an Average (2d) Discipline check to move or control it."  I can see the argument from both sides about whether or not the player needs to roll every time she wants to move the fire.  Personally, I would argue that this means you only need to do it once.  Asking a player to roll an Average (2d) Discipline check every turn seems excessive. The fire only doubles in size once (presumably) so you should only need one check to see if you are able to control this new larger sized fire.  This certainly could be more clear on the card, but I think only rolling once to control or move seems right.